# how to get more accurate/sensitive colliding

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently one solid object goes in to(solid obj. sinking in to another solid obj. ) another object when I use ontriggerenter with 1 trigger and other is rigidbody&collider object

but I need to use oncolliderenter to get instantly on point collide. not sinking like collide .

How should I set up my objects? which must be rigidbody ? (btw I dont wantto use gravity I am now using animations. when ball hits plane ball must trigger animation on point collide)

Comment: Trigger volumes are specifically not solid.

Answer (score 1):

From Unity3D's Manual section on [Colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) near the bottom:

## Collision action matrix

When two objects collide, a number of different script events can occur depending on the configurations of the colliding objects’ rigidbodies. The charts below give details of which event functions are called based on the components that are attached to the objects. Some of the combinations only cause one of the two objects to be affected by the collision, but the general rule is that physics will not be applied to an object that doesn’t have a Rigidbody component attached.

### Collision detection occurs and messages are sent upon collision

```
+======================================+=================+====================+==============================+=========================+============================+======================================+
|                                      | Static Collider | Rigidbody Collider | Kinematic Rigidbody Collider | Static Trigger Collider | Rigidbody Trigger Collider | Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider |
+======================================+=================+====================+==============================+=========================+============================+======================================+
| Static Collider                      |                 | Y                  |                              |                         |                            |                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Rigidbody Collider                   | Y               | Y                  | Y                            |                         |                            |                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Kinematic Rigidbody Collider         |                 | Y                  |                              |                         |                            |                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Static Trigger Collider              |                 |                    |                              |                         |                            |                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Rigidbody Trigger Collider           |                 |                    |                              |                         |                            |                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider |                 |                    |                              |                         |                            |                                      |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

### Trigger messages are sent upon collision

```
+======================================+=================+====================+==============================+=========================+============================+======================================+
|                                      | Static Collider | Rigidbody Collider | Kinematic Rigidbody Collider | Static Trigger Collider | Rigidbody Trigger Collider | Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider |
+======================================+=================+====================+==============================+=========================+============================+======================================+
| Static Collider                      |                 |                    |                              |                         | Y                          | Y                                    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Rigidbody Collider                   |                 |                    |                              | Y                       | Y                          | Y                                    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Kinematic Rigidbody Collider         |                 |                    |                              | Y                       | Y                          | Y                                    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Static Trigger Collider              |                 | Y                  | Y                            |                         | Y                          | Y                                    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Rigidbody Trigger Collider           | Y               | Y                  | Y                            | Y                       | Y                          | Y                                    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Kinematic Rigidbody Trigger Collider | Y               | Y                  | Y                            | Y                       | Y                          | Y                                    |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This saved me to rewrite my code "but the general rule is that physics will not be applied to an object that doesn’t have a Rigidbody component attached." It's not realy truth, but without rigidbody the trigger events are more slow and inaccurate.

Comment: I think without a Rigidbody, the physics engine doesn't know how to move the collided object. If it moved, it was statically moved through the transform